# List ADF Self-hosted Integration Runtimes

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-powershell, powershell-core

I have an ADF which has a number of Self Hosted Integration Runtimes.  I'm trying to get a listing of all the self hosted IRs but I only want to return the IRs that are Original to the ADF I'm working with.  I don't want to return the IRs that are shared from another ADF.

I have the following code:

```
Get-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -ResourceGroupName RG1QA -DatafactoryName ADFQA | where type -eq "SelfHosted" | Select Name
```

That command brings back all the SHIRs, including the ones that are shared from the PRD ADF.  We only need the IRs that are Original to ADFQA.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot find exact command to get only Original IR’s.

I have tried below **workaround**.
I have 4 IR’s. I added Description to them as “*Shared*” and “*Not Shared*”.

[image]

[image]

Finally run `Get-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -ResourceGroupName ******** -DataFactoryName ********* | where Description -eq "Not Shared"| Select name` command to get names of all IR’s that are not Shared.

[image]

Comment: Looks like that might be the best way to single out whether an IR is shared or not, by adding a note on the description.